# Json : find the maximum number

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I want to find the maximum value from a json array

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "item_id": "129",
        "item_name": "HP Leserjet",
        "item_quantity": "10",
        "item_rate": "80000.75",
        "item_purchase_date": "2020-05-13T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "130",
        "item_name": "HP Leserjet",
        "item_quantity": "10",
        "item_rate": "80000.75",
        "item_purchase_date": "2020-05-13T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "131",
        "item_name": "HP Leserjet",
        "item_quantity": "10",
        "item_rate": "80000.75",
        "item_purchase_date": "2020-05-13T00:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

Lets says this long json is saved in a variable called **posts** . I must use **for of** loop (since I am inside `typescript`) . [I wish it could be a simple c loop]

anyway, here is how I tried. I need to find the maximum **item_id** . I don't know why it didn't work

**file.ts**

```
  makeMaxId()
  { let x = 0;
    for (let post of this.posts) {
      if (post[0] > x)
      {
        x = this.post[0];
      }
    }
    console.log(x);
  }
```

Comment: You want only maximun item_id or whole object?

Comment: Maximum of which field? Inside your code, `post` holds reference to each object in array, nowhere else, and your objects do not have a field with the key '0'. So, you always get `undefined` when you refer `post[0]` .

Comment: @VikasKeskar yes

Comment: @keskinsaf maximum of item_id , so i mean 1st index , index[0]

Comment: then try that: ... post['item_id'] > x ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 makeMaxId(){
    let x = 0;
    for (let post of this.posts) {
      if (post['item_id'] > x)
      {
        x = post['item_id'];
      }
    }
    console.log(x);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following statement will give you maximum item_id

```
Math.max(...this.posts.map(p => Number(p.item_id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
const mySortedPosts = this.posts.sort((a, b) => {
  return Number(b.item_id) - Number(a.item_id)
})

mySortedPosts[0] // <-- post with greatest item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let B= A.map(item =>parseInt(item.item_id));
console.log(Math.max(...B));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.